# How to spawn windows from other windows in GTK? (using C)

Tags: c, events, gtk, window

I was reading about GTK+-2.0, and everthing seemed cool enough. Then when I actually got to programming, I realized I had now idea how to make a new window pop up with a button press. I suppose I could make the button "clicked" event fork/exec another GTK program, but come on, there's gotta be an easier way to do something this simple, right? If you know how to do this, or can direct me to a source which does, I would certainly appreciate it. Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just another GTKWidget *window, display it once the signal for your button is called.

Comment: Thanks, I had been trying that to no avail. I guess I just wasn't trying the right way. Finally got it.